# is it required to make foreign key as not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it required to make foreign key column in a table as NOT NULL,
If we not written explicitly foreign key column as not null what it will be?
Can it contain null values?

And what is the Difference between following two statements:

```
[PhoneId] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_PhoneNumber](PhoneNumberId)
[PhoneId] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_PhoneNumber](PhoneNumberId)
```

Comment: The difference is that the second definition will allow Nulls in the column. The relationships will be `1 :: 0..n` in the first and `0..1 :: 0..n` in the second (if you are familiar with this notation).

Comment: @ypercube - That depends on the ANSI null default database option and whether or not the client library calls [`SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

> Is it required to make foreign key column in a table as NOT NULL,

No it is not required. MSDN says that:-

> When a value other than NULL is entered into the column of a FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint, the value must exist in the referenced column;
>   otherwise, a foreign key violation error message is returned. To make
>   sure that all values of a composite foreign key constraint are
>   verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating columns.

So the simple answer to your question is NO IT IS NOT REQUIRED.

A foreign key attribute can contain NULL values as well.

Your second definition will allow `Nulls` in the column.

From [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/):-

> When a FOREIGN KEY constraint is added to an existing column or
>   columns in the table SQL Server, by default checks the existing data
>   in the columns to ensure that all values, except NULL, exist in the
>   column(s) of the referenced PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.

Also check **[Foreign Key Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

According to sql normalization rule foreign key value must be equal to primary key value or NULL, so it will contain either NULL value of one value from primary key table row.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required. A foreign key attribute without `NOT NULL` can contain `NULL` values, and this can be used to indicate that no such tuple in the referenced relation is applicable.

Comment: Means by default it can contain null values also!

Comment: @DhananjayPatil:- Yes it may contain NULL values!